# Modify Streamlit session_state on HTML button click

Tags: javascript, python, streamlit

I'm creating a button with custom CSS using HTML in Streamlit (button_html), but I can't apply an EventListener to change st.session_state.page when clicked. How can I achieve this while preserving the custom CSS styling?

```
button_html = f"""
                <div class="container sub">
                    <button class='view-button'> 
                        View
                    </button>
                </div>
            """

            st.markdown(button_html, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

I've tried writing script for it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please provide the script you've tried?

Comment: @AlanBagel

`button_script = f"""
        <script>
            function handleClick() {{
                {st.session_state.page = 'browse_movies'}
            }}
        </script>
    """`

no matter what the content inside the function is, whenever I click the button, I get the following error:

Uncaught Error: Minified React error #231; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=231&args[]=onClick&args[]=string for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

Comment: Check out this doc: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/components/components-api